# The head of my linked list suddenly dissapears/gets reset to null

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I've been staring at this bit of code for what feels like a week and can't figure out what's going on. I currently have a `LinkedList` that needs to add 500 elements. On the first run through where I'm adding element 0, it works fine. It sees that it's the first element, creates a new head, and moves on. The problem is when the code comes back around to add element 1, the head has suddenly been reset to null, so it goes and makes another head, kicking out the previous head. On the third run, the code recognizes that there is a head, and attempts to add element 2. However, the size variable `n` claims there are 2 elements in the `LinkedList`, when there really is only one because the first head vanished. Therefore, a `NullPointerException` is thrown when looking for that second element. What is happening to that first head? It makes it all the way through the `add()` method, but isn't there when it comes back. But it is there when it comes back again?

Here's the specific method where everything is going wrong:

```
public void add(int i, value_type value) {
    n++;
    System.out.println(head==null);
    if (i < 0 || i >= size())
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

    System.out.println(i);
    ListNode<value_type> tmp;
    if (head == null) {
        System.out.println("0");
        head = new ListNode<value_type>(value, head);
    } else {
        System.out.println("1");
        tmp = head;
        for (int k=0; k < i-1; k++) {
            System.out.println("For Loop Reached");
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }
        if (i == 1) {
            ListNode<value_type> u = new ListNode<value_type>(value);
            tmp.next = u;
        }

        tmp.next = new ListNode<value_type>(value);

    }
    System.out.println(head==null);
    System.out.println("");
}
```

And here's the whole class:

```
   /**
 * 
 */
package data_structures;

import com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.graph.Node;

/**
 * @author 
 *
 */

/**
 * The ListNode<value_type> is a helper class for your 
 * LinkedList<value_type> class.  As its not intended for use
 * outside the LinkeList class, we are keeping it simple -- the
 * two properties will be access directly, instead of going through
 * inspectors and mutators.
 * 
 * DO NOT MODIFY THIST CLASS.
 * 
 * @param <value_type>  The type of object to be stored in the list.
 */
class ListNode<value_type> {
    public value_type value;
    public ListNode<value_type> next;

    public ListNode(value_type v) {
        value = v;
        next = null;
    }

    public ListNode(value_type v, ListNode<value_type> n) {
        value = v;
        next = n;
    }

}


/*
 * We will implement this as a single linked list.
 */
public class LinkedList<value_type> extends Sequence<value_type> {

    /**
     * head will be the first node of the list -- or null if the list is empty
     */
    private ListNode<value_type> head;  


    /**
     * List constructor: must call the superclass constructor.
     */
    public LinkedList() {
        super();
        head = null; 
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see data_structures.Sequence#get(int)
     */
    @Override
    public value_type get(int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= size())
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        ListNode<value_type> tmp = head;
        for (int k=0; k < i; k++) {
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }


        return tmp.value;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see data_structures.Sequence#set(int, java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public value_type set(int i, value_type value) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= size())
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        if (head == null) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }

        ListNode<value_type> tmp = head;
        for (int k=0; k < i; k++) {
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }

        if (tmp == null) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }

        return tmp.value;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see data_structures.Sequence#add(int, java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public void add(int i, value_type value) {
        n++;
        System.out.println(head==null);
        if (i < 0 || i >= size())
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        System.out.println(i);
        ListNode<value_type> tmp;
        if (head == null) {
            System.out.println("0");
            head = new ListNode<value_type>(value, head);
        } else {
            System.out.println("1");
            tmp = head;
            for (int k=0; k < i-1; k++) {
                System.out.println("For Loop Reached");
                tmp = tmp.next;
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                ListNode<value_type> u = new ListNode<value_type>(value);
                tmp.next = u;
            }

            tmp.next = new ListNode<value_type>(value);

        }
        System.out.println(head==null);
        System.out.println("");

    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see data_structures.Sequence#remove(int)
     */
    @Override
    public value_type remove(int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= size())
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        ListNode<value_type> tmp = head;
        for (int k=0; k < i; k++) {
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }

        ListNode<value_type> a = tmp;
        ListNode<value_type> b = tmp.next.next;
        a.next = b;

        return tmp.value;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see data_structures.Sequence#clear()
     */
    @Override
    public void clear() {
        head = null;
    }



}
```

Comment: Can you please share the usage of this linked list with your real code?

Comment: You mean the rest of the code in my project?

Comment: The `remove` function is not safe for removing the head and it is buggy. It may be the problem. I suggest you to look at example linked list implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by adding special cases for when `i=0` and `i=1` as I believe Gene was referencing to. I also added a tail variable for adding onto the end of the list.

```
public void add(int i, value_type value) {
    if (i < 0 || i > size())
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

    //if the size of the list is 0, create a new head
    if (n==0) {
        head = new ListNode<value_type>(value, head);
        tail = head;
    } else if (i==0) { //if the size isn't 0, but i is 0, add a new head
        ListNode<value_type> u = new ListNode<value_type>(value, head);
        head = u;
    } else if (i==n) { //if adding onto the end, make a new tail
        ListNode<value_type> u = new ListNode<value_type>(value);
        tail.next = u;
        tail = u;           
    } else { //else, traverse through the list to the appropriate spot
        ListNode<value_type> tmp;
        tmp = head;
        for(int k=0; k < i-1; k++) {
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }
        ListNode<value_type> u = new ListNode<value_type>(value, tmp.next);
        tmp.next = u;
    }

    n++; //increase the size of the list by 1

}
```

The rest of the fixed class is below:

```
 /**
 * 
 */
package data_structures;

import com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.graph.Node;

/**
 * The ListNode<value_type> is a helper class for your 
 * LinkedList<value_type> class.  As its not intended for use
 * outside the LinkeList class, we are keeping it simple -- the
 * two properties will be access directly, instead of going through
 * inspectors and mutators.
 * 
 * DO NOT MODIFY THIST CLASS.
 * 
 * @param <value_type>  The type of object to be stored in the list.
 */
class ListNode<value_type> {
    public value_type value;
    public ListNode<value_type> next;

    public ListNode(value_type v) {
        value = v;
        next = null;
    }

    public ListNode(value_type v, ListNode<value_type> n) {
        value = v;
        next = n;
    }

}


/*
 * We will implement this as a single linked list.
 */
public class LinkedList<value_type> extends Sequence<value_type> {

    /**
     * head will be the first node of the list -- or null if the list is empty
     */
    private ListNode<value_type> head, tail;                      

    /**
     * List constructor: must call the superclass constructor.
     */
    public LinkedList() {
        super();
        head = null; 
        tail = null;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see data_structures.Sequence#get(int)
     */
    @Override
    public value_type get(int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= size())
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();


        ListNode<value_type> tmp = head;
        if (i==0) {
            return head.value;
        } else {
            for (int k=0; k < i; k++) {
                tmp = tmp.next;
            }
        }


        return tmp.value;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see data_structures.Sequence#set(int, java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public value_type set(int i, value_type value) {
        System.out.println(n);
        if (i < 0 || i >= size())
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        if (i==0) {
            value_type s = head.value;
            head.value = value;
            return s;
        } else {
            ListNode<value_type> tmp = head;
            for (int k=0; k < i; k++) {
                tmp = tmp.next;
            }
            value_type s = tmp.value;
            tmp.value = value;
            return s;
        }
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see data_structures.Sequence#add(int, java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public void add(int i, value_type value) {
        if (i < 0 || i > size())
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        if (n==0) {
            head = new ListNode<value_type>(value, head);
            tail = head;
        } else if (i==0) {
            ListNode<value_type> u = new ListNode<value_type>(value, head);
            head = u;
        } else if (i==n) {
            ListNode<value_type> u = new ListNode<value_type>(value);
            tail.next = u;
            tail = u;           
        } else {
            ListNode<value_type> tmp;
            tmp = head;
            for(int k=0; k < i-1; k++) {
                tmp = tmp.next;
            }
            ListNode<value_type> u = new ListNode<value_type>(value, tmp.next);
            tmp.next = u;
        }

        n++;

    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see data_structures.Sequence#remove(int)
     */
    @Override
    public value_type remove(int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= size())
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        ListNode<value_type> tmp = head;
        if (i==0) {
            if (n==1) {
                head.next = null;
                n--;
                return head.value;
            } else {
                value_type save = head.value;
                head = head.next;
                n--;
                return save;
            }
        }
        for (int k=0; k < i-1; k++) {
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }

        ListNode<value_type> a = tmp;
        value_type save = tmp.next.value;
        ListNode<value_type> b = tmp.next.next;
        a.next = b;

        n--;

        return save;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see data_structures.Sequence#clear()
     */
    @Override
    public void clear() {
        head = null;
        n = 0;
        tail=null;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is pretty broken. You'll learn by fixing it yourself.

The special case for handling insertion correctly is not when `head` is `null`. It's when you want to insert at position 0.  The logic is roughly

```
if desired insert position is 0 // we're inserting at head
   head = new node(val, head); // new head points to old rest of list (maybe null)
else
   tmp = head;
   advance tmp to point to the element before the desired position.
   tmp.next = new node(val, tmp.next); // insert at desired position
```

In the last step, you are making the node preceding the desired position point to the new node and the new node point to the old "next" element, which is exactly right.  This can work only when there *is* an element before the desired position. That's true whenever the desired position is greater than 0.

In this discussion I'm ignoring desired positions outside the list. You need to add `throw` logic for them.

Finally, note that for learning this is fine, but in a real system you'd never build a list of 500 elements this way.  By the time you're inserting the 500th element, advancing to the desired positions requires 498 loop iterations. There are much more efficient ways.

Comment: So when I want to add an element to the end of the list, I can't just call `tmp.next`, and set it to a new node, because `tmp.next` does not exist yet? So I need to create a node that has the new node set as its `next` and then add those two to the end of the list? That feels cumbersome.